# Visualizing an association btw two discrete variables via diagram in R

Tags: r, diagram

Assume two variables (`state` and `group`). Instances of `state` (*s*) may share a property with specific instances of `group` (*g*). For example, *s1*, *s2* and *s3* may have an association with *g1*.

I would like to visualize the association between the two variables in the form of a diagram like to one displayed below:

[image]

I would like to generate such a diagram with R. What R package would you recommend me to use?

Comment: I'd recommend having a look here: http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/ The demo (video) will give you an idea about what you can do.

Comment: This looks a bit like **Sankey diagrams**. There are several R packages that can produce these.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for the pointer on a more appropriate name! Yes, the type of graph I aim to generate is quite similar to a Sankey diagram, but compared to a genuine Sankey diagram, where the "width of the arrows is shown proportionally to the flow quantity" (source: Wikipedia on 'Sankey diagram'), the dataset I aim to visualize does not have any variable on flow quantity. I am looking to visualize a mere association.

Comment: @AntoniosK The package you recommended generates network graph diagrams. Such a diagram would not be fitting here, as there can be no associations within a variable, only between variables in my data.

Comment: Maybe `e <- read.table(sep=",", text="s1,g1\n
s2,g1\n
s3,g1\n
s4,g2\n
s5,g2\n
s6,g2\n
s7,g3\n
s8,g4\n
s9,g5\n
s10,g5");library(igraph);g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(e));V(g)$type <- bipartite.mapping(g)$type;
coords <- layout_as_bipartite(g);plot(g,layout = -coords[,2:1])`.

Comment: I think the package will pick the associations you specify. If they exist only between variables and not within variables that will be picked up and showed in the diagram. Something like the `igraph` package that @lukeA posted above.

Comment: @lukeA You read my mind. That is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of [lukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea), I came up with the following code that addresses the above-mentioned need.

In Shell:

```
$ cat table
s1  g1
s2  g1
s3  g1
s4  g2
s5  g2
s6  g2
s7  g3
s8  g4
s9  g5
s10 g5
```

In R:

```
library(igraph)

# Reading data from file
m <- as.matrix(read.table(file="~/Desktop/table", sep="\t"))

# Generating igraph
g <- graph_from_edgelist(m, directed=FALSE)
V(g)$type <- bipartite.mapping(g)$type
coords <- layout_as_bipartite(g)

# Plotting operations
plot.igraph(g, layout = -coords[,2:1]) # Preliminary plotting (why necessary?)
plot.igraph(g, layout = -coords[,2:1],
    vertex.shape="rectangle", # For vertex.foo and edge.foo commands, see: http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html
    vertex.size=50,
    vertex.size2=20,
    vertex.color=NA,
    vertex.label.color= "black")

# Adding title to plot
title("My first igraph")
```

[image]